# Android studio Gradle error(JAVA)?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIk0w.png)I am new to Android. Please share the solution for this. I installed the android studio then i am getting below error in Gradle  console when I was compile my program.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.global.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: C:\Users\GLOBAL\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\global\myapplication\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:coldswapKickerDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3 mins 44.997 secs
Information:61 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Can you show your app's build.gradle

Comment: i have edited my question ples check it

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: i haven't checked. i will update ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, there is a line which says

```
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
```

The error is due to low heap size specified. Anyway, you can solve this by adding this to your build.gradle

```
android {
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}
```

Please try this and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

The `52.0` class version is used in Java 1.8. It seems that you are using a JDK with a lower version. Try upgrading it to 1.8.

Comment: that's the problem. JDK 7 can not read Java 8 files. Update to JDK 8 (which is really 1.8)

Comment: @Keerthana, just a reminder: you should consider upvoting and/or accepting answers that answers your questions.